# How to design mysql tables that follow multiple values from each other

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make something of a vacation website where a user can follow certain vacations.

Right now there are 2 tables, one for vacations and one for users.
I want to make it so when a user decides to follow a vacation, it will be somehow associated with him like a column of "followedVacations" that would contain the ids of the vacations he's following.

Problem is what if he is following multiple vacations? how do i store that information with the user, or alternatively store on the vacation entry which users are following it?

I am using mysql, react and node if that has any relevancy

I don't know how to make it work so i couldn't really try anything

iv'e got no code to show because i dont know how to approach this on a table and schema design level

I'm basically looking for the correct way to do this.

Edit: Would it be possible to also have amount of followers on the vacation table?

Comment: 1) Can a user follow more that one vacation? 2) Can one vacation relate to more than one user?

Comment: A user should be able to follow any amount of vacations, and vacations arent exclusive to a user

Comment: OK, and can one vacation be followed by more than one user?

Comment: Yes, a vacation can have any amount of followers

Comment: OK thanks. Please see the answer by @TimBiegeleisen: this looks like the correct solution to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard approach here would be to create a third *junction* table which relates users to vacations and vice-versa.  So, you might have the following three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)

CREATE TABLE vacations (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    location VARCHAR(50),
    price DECIMAL(10,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE user_vacations (
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    vacation_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, vacation_id)
)
```

Note that the junction `user_vacations` table mainly exists to relate users to vacations.  All the metadata associated with a user or vacation would continue to be stored in your current two tables which already exist.

Comment: So on the junction table i will have every user-vacation relationship in a separate entry? If you please can show a quick example how i would use that to see all vacations a user is follow or for a vacation all users following it?

Comment: Yes, that is my suggestion.  It also assumes that the same relationship doesn't need to be store more than once.